XUnit testing with third party API
I am using a third party API which inserts a record into the database. The basic setup of my project is:
Repository
public class MyRepository
{
    public void InsertRecord(Customer c)
    {
     //call third party API/method to insert
    }
}

Controllers
public IActionResult AddCustomer (Customer model)
{
    try
    {
        _myRepo.InsertRecord(model)
    }
    catch (Exception1 ex)
    {
       //return Error to page
    }
    catch (Exception2 ext)
    {
       //return Error to page
    }
}

This works as intended. I would like to introduce xUnit and have set it all up. I am testing MyRepository and not the Controller. To me i am going to copy the try catch blocks into my Unit Tests but came across a few issues, here is what i have so far (other code removed as it didnt compile or work the way i thought it works):
[Fact]
public void InsertRecordMock
{
     Mock<Customer> cust;
     // Set up cust object
     _myRepo.InsertRecord(cust);    
}

The problems are:

If i use it this way and it works it would write to my database. In my research i read there should be no dependency on a database or anything. The API is third party so how could i test it then?

The method is a void, i read the documentation and most examples are expecting some type of return e.g.
 var caughtException = Assert.Throws<Exception>(action);



but i dont have an Action methd so this leads me to think i cant test a void and some of the examples ive seen who do test a void dont explain very well to overcome this. How could i test this scenario?

EF had an in-memory provider but now they discourage it. I guess there's no harm in using an actual db for integration tests.

There shouldn't be a lot of logic in your repository, that's not related to the third party, so it doesn't make sense to unit test it. Instead do one of the following:

Do an integration test with the actual API.
Mock the API and pass that to the repository.

Furthermore: Why are you mocking the customer? Isn't it just data? You should mock dependencies of your class, but I don't see how the customer is one.
And finally: voids throw exceptions too, I don't see what your problem is with that.

I was Mocking the cust as the insert method accepts a cust and yes its just data but to test that the bizarre data entered passes the test. Yes void throws exceptions but i felt adding try catch to the Unit test just means im repeating the Controller actions?

You can just do var cust = new Customer {BizarreData = "@#!"}; You should only mock when you cannot use the concrete implementation. Every mock us a deviation from how it will be in the application, thus lowering the value of your test.

I see what you mean, what about the void testing, yes it has exceptions am i just surrounding it with try catch blocks or is there a better way?
